# Al generar de nuevo un apk no registra los cambios

Tags: android, cordova, apk

Hice cambios en mi proyecto cordova, luego eliminé la carpeta de plugins, la de node-modules y la de platforms y generé todo de nuevo. Conseguí generar el archivo apk sin problemas, no dio error. El problema es que cuando instalé la app en el teléfono resulta que es la versión antigua (eliminé también en el teléfono la versión anterior antes de instalar la  nueva), el nuevo fichero apk no contiene los nuevos cambios, en cambio, si hago npm run debug, si que veo los cambios. ¿Que puede estar pasando?

Gracias,

un saludo.

Comment: Hola! Creo que tal vez podrías hacer un re-build y verificar que tienes todos los cambios.

Answer (score 0):

Asegúrate que el código de la última versión está en el directorio www del proyecto cordova. Según la tecnología que estés utilizando puede que tengas que hacer un `build` de tu app antes de lanzar `cordova build`.

Por ejemplo, en ionic se suele utilizar `ionic cordova build` en vez de solo `cordova build`. De esa forma te aseguras que primero se compila la app en ionic y la deposita en el directorio www antes de lanzar el build de cordova